# Does it make any difference if we change the position of operands in a logical statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the following function in python which returns a sublist (i.e. the part of the list that it had been iterating through until it finds a particular value (in my case 5) without including it in the sublist and also stops iterating further).

```
def sublist(a):
    b=[]
    i=0
    while(a[i]!=5 and i<=len(a)-1):
        b.append(a[i])
        i=i+1
    return b
```

the above function worked fine with all test cases except this one `a=[1, 6, 2, 3, 9]`. It gave the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

But when I interchanged the operands of the while loop condition and wrote the same code in the following way I got output for all the test cases:

```
def sublist(a):
    b=[]
    i=0
    while(i<=len(a)-1 and a[i]!=5):
        b.append(a[i])
        i=i+1
    return b
```

Why didn't I get output in the first case?

Comment: As your example demonstrates, the answer to your title question is "yes". Note that in the first version you're using `a[i]` **before** checking `i<=len(a)-1` (which can be simplified to `i < len(a)`).

Answer (score 1):

It's called "logical short-circuit", when a logical expression has to be evaluate the programming language watch the first operand and says like:
"This is an OR, if the first operand is okay for me the whole expression is okay!"
And so it ignores the second one.

For the AND it's the same thing but:
"This is an AND, if the first operand is okay i've to check the second, otherwise the whole expression is not okay"

In this case into the while you first check for a[i] that

> MIGHT

throw an exception and then for i<=len(a)-1.

I made a little of ELI5.

Edit: 
I forgot if you don't use parenthesis also watch this table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Order_of_precedence

Also as a computer sciencetist you must have a VERY good knowledge about short-ciruit, it can help you a lot with performances

Comment: thanks a lot matteo..it was really helpful..,much appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

when you call `sublist` with `a=[1, 6, 2, 3, 9]` the i in the while loop is incremented further after 4 and becomes i=5.

Since you have placed the condition on i after `a[i]!=5` the function checks this condition before the `i<=len(a)-1` condition.
But since `a[5]` doesn't exist this throws an error and never moves on to check the condition on i, effectively terminating the further execution of your program.

But if you switch the order of the conditions inside while loop.
`i=5` comes and meets the condition that i should be less than or equal to four (`i<=4`) and the second condition is never executed since the first one failed (because of the and logic). And since second condition is the reason for our error you won't get that error this time.